# Android gradle version 8.2.2 failed to build with Multiple build operations failed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

```
// Project Gradle
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.4" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.22-1.0.16" apply false
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}



// App Gradle

compileOptions {
    isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}



coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4")


from changing version 8.1.4 to 

id("com.android.application") version "8.1.4" apply false


8.2.2
id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false


causes the issue with message

Multiple build operations failed.
coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
```

and logcat with

[image]

```
> Task :buildSrc:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Multiple build operations failed.
    coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
    coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Multiple build operations failed.
    coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
    coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:439)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:146)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
```